# How do I still have entries in grub2?

Tags: fedora, boot, grub2

I followed these 2 links:

- https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2#Instructions_for_UEFI-based_systems
- https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/latest/system-administrators-guide/kernel-module-driver-configuration/Working_with_the_GRUB_2_Boot_Loader/#sec-Reinstalling_GRUB_2

But I still have garbage kernel versions that aren't installed anymore.

Why? How can I remove them?

[image: boot]

I should only see 2 kernel versions...

```
$ ls -alh /boot
total 231M
dr-xr-xr-x.  5 root root 4.0K Jun 29 15:57 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 20 root root 4.0K Jun  5 10:43 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 252K Jun 14 09:00 config-6.3.8-350.vanilla.fc38.x86_64
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 253K Jun 26 09:00 config-6.4.0-358.vanilla.fc38.x86_64
drwx------   3 root root 4.0K Jan  1  1970 efi
drwx------.  3 root root   50 Apr 12 09:00 grub2
-rw-------.  1 root root 105M May 18 11:25 initramfs-0-rescue-71951923e9e0421e907793420ba59140.img
-rw-------   1 root root  35M Jun 15 11:35 initramfs-6.3.8-350.vanilla.fc38.x86_64.img
-rw-------   1 root root  35M Jun 29 15:17 initramfs-6.4.0-358.vanilla.fc38.x86_64.img
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root   21 May 18 11:22 loader
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   53 Jun 15 11:35 symvers-6.3.8-350.vanilla.fc38.x86_64.gz -> /lib/modules/6.3.8-350.vanilla.fc38.x86_64/symvers.gz
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   53 Jun 29 15:17 symvers-6.4.0-358.vanilla.fc38.x86_64.xz -> /lib/modules/6.4.0-358.vanilla.fc38.x86_64/symvers.xz
-rw-------   1 root root 8.2M Jun 14 09:00 System.map-6.3.8-350.vanilla.fc38.x86_64
-rw-------   1 root root 8.2M Jun 26 09:00 System.map-6.4.0-358.vanilla.fc38.x86_64
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root  14M May 18 11:23 vmlinuz-0-rescue-71951923e9e0421e907793420ba59140
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  14M Jun 14 09:00 vmlinuz-6.3.8-350.vanilla.fc38.x86_64
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  168 Jun 14 09:00 .vmlinuz-6.3.8-350.vanilla.fc38.x86_64.hmac
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  14M Jun 26 09:00 vmlinuz-6.4.0-358.vanilla.fc38.x86_64
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  168 Jun 26 09:00 .vmlinuz-6.4.0-358.vanilla.fc38.x86_64.hmac
```

Grubby still shows them:

```
# grubby --info=ALL
index=0
kernel="/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-0.rc0.20230628gt6aeadf78.260.vanilla.fc38.x86_64"
args="ro rhgb quiet memhp_default_state=offline"
root="UUID=ebbbb014-e320-4361-b90c-e70f519a0fee"
initrd="/boot/initramfs-6.5.0-0.rc0.20230628gt6aeadf78.260.vanilla.fc38.x86_64.img"
title="Fedora Linux (6.5.0-0.rc0.20230628gt6aeadf78.260.vanilla.fc38.x86_64) 38 (Server Edition)"
id="71951923e9e0421e907793420ba59140-6.5.0-0.rc0.20230628gt6aeadf78.260.vanilla.fc38.x86_64"
index=1
kernel="/boot/vmlinuz-6.4.0-358.vanilla.fc38.x86_64"
args="ro rhgb quiet memhp_default_state=offline"
root="UUID=ebbbb014-e320-4361-b90c-e70f519a0fee"
initrd="/boot/initramfs-6.4.0-358.vanilla.fc38.x86_64.img"
title="Fedora Linux (6.4.0-358.vanilla.fc38.x86_64) 38 (Server Edition)"
id="71951923e9e0421e907793420ba59140-6.4.0-358.vanilla.fc38.x86_64"
index=2
kernel="/boot/vmlinuz-6.4.0-0.rc6.20230616gt40f71e7c.349.vanilla.fc38.x86_64"
args="ro rhgb quiet memhp_default_state=offline"
root="UUID=ebbbb014-e320-4361-b90c-e70f519a0fee"
initrd="/boot/initramfs-6.4.0-0.rc6.20230616gt40f71e7c.349.vanilla.fc38.x86_64.img"
title="Fedora Linux (6.4.0-0.rc6.20230616gt40f71e7c.349.vanilla.fc38.x86_64) 38 (Server Edition)"
id="71951923e9e0421e907793420ba59140-6.4.0-0.rc6.20230616gt40f71e7c.349.vanilla.fc38.x86_64"
index=3
kernel="/boot/vmlinuz-6.3.8-350.vanilla.fc38.x86_64"
args="ro rhgb quiet memhp_default_state=offline"
root="UUID=ebbbb014-e320-4361-b90c-e70f519a0fee"
initrd="/boot/initramfs-6.3.8-350.vanilla.fc38.x86_64.img"
title="Fedora Linux (6.3.8-350.vanilla.fc38.x86_64) 38 (Server Edition)"
id="71951923e9e0421e907793420ba59140-6.3.8-350.vanilla.fc38.x86_64"
index=4
kernel="/boot/vmlinuz-6.3.8-0.rc1.20230612gt718be390.350.vanilla.fc38.x86_64"
args="ro rhgb quiet memhp_default_state=offline"
root="UUID=ebbbb014-e320-4361-b90c-e70f519a0fee"
initrd="/boot/initramfs-6.3.8-0.rc1.20230612gt718be390.350.vanilla.fc38.x86_64.img"
title="Fedora Linux (6.3.8-0.rc1.20230612gt718be390.350.vanilla.fc38.x86_64) 38 (Server Edition)"
id="71951923e9e0421e907793420ba59140-6.3.8-0.rc1.20230612gt718be390.350.vanilla.fc38.x86_64"
index=5
kernel="/boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-71951923e9e0421e907793420ba59140"
args="ro rhgb quiet memhp_default_state=offline"
root="UUID=ebbbb014-e320-4361-b90c-e70f519a0fee"
initrd="/boot/initramfs-0-rescue-71951923e9e0421e907793420ba59140.img"
title="Fedora Linux (0-rescue-71951923e9e0421e907793420ba59140) 38 (Server Edition)"
id="71951923e9e0421e907793420ba59140-0-rescue"
```

Comment: I know in debian you use `update-grub` (a simple script that calls `grub-mkconfig`) when you want to actually update grub

Comment: I found the issue, the kernel packages were still installed... grub2 uses DNF/YUM to build the menuentry, not what is under /boot

Comment: Check the contents of your `/boot/loader` and/or `/boot/efi/loader` directories. If they exist, they might contain small text files that identify the kernel versions installed - mostly for `systemd-boot`, but I think the newer versions of GRUB as used in modern Fedora/RHEL/CentOS Streams can use those files too, to build the boot menu at run-time as opposed to `grub[2]-mkconfig` time.